# How to render stylesheets to page view

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Am pretty new with rails and trying to learn by watching videos online.
Am following a tutorial on how to make a blog in rails and everything seems quite good but the guy in the tutorial adds some new folders in stylesheets namely:

**Modules**, **Partials** and **Pages**
then added a `_buttons.scss` in pages folder
and added some css over there, from his end everything was working nice but i did exactly the same and nothing happend, but when i added the same css in my `application.css.scss` it worked for me.

My question is what makes this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rails asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives). Compiles your files. If you do in application.css

```
/* ...
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/.
```

it will recursively require everything in the directory. You can also specifically require the file you want.